# How to turn off auto increment for field ID in List?

Tags: list-item, synchronization

I need to synchronize data from mysql into listitem in sharepoint, and keep values of ID when synchronized to ListItem, but I can not insert ID value.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find that this is not possible. If you need to maintain the sql id for historical purposes, you could create a field in your list called OriginalId and sync the sql id to that field.